# Using D3 to draw background gridline paths in a matrix for scatterplots?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, path, line, scatter-plot

I've been able to draw most of the visual components of a scatterplot.

I now want to draw some background gridlines using a lighter color.  In other words, every X coordinate will have a corresponding vertical background gridline that goes the full height of the Y axis and every Y coordinate will have a corresponding horizontal background gridline that goes the full width of the X axis.

I've attempted to draw the horizontal paths using the following code:

```
    // Create horizontal paths...
    var horizontalGrids = innerCanvas
        .data(yAxisData)
      .append("path")
        //.attr("d", lineFunction(dataSet))
        .attr("d", function(d, i){
          var p1 = {x: 0, y: yAxisScale(d)};
          var p2 = {x: marginRight-100, y: yAxisScale(d)};
          var pts = [];
          pts.push(p1);
          pts.push(p2);
          return lineFunction(pts);
        })
        .attr("stroke", "gray")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("fill", "gray");
```

The code for lineFunction is:

```
    var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
      .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
      .interpolate("linear");
```

The data array being passed in and used for yAxisData is:

```
var seasonsArray = ["Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Autumn"];
```

The intent is to draw four (4) separate horizontal path lines, one for each element of array "seasonsArray".

However, this only seems to draw one horizontal path (i.e. the first path line) and seems to ignore all others.  It seems as if the data() binding is not working properly.

You can see the problem in the Scatterplot section titled "*Let's use paths to throw in some grid lines:*", in the following visual example: http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/raw/9ae1b738088761f135e1/

The original code can be found at: https://gist.github.com/Guerino1/9ae1b738088761f135e1

The full function in the original code which contains the above code snippet is called "draw6(...)".

Any thoughts as to what the problem is?

Comment: What is the code of lineFunction()?

Comment: I added the code for lineFunction, above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't [thinking with joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/). The pattern is `selectAll`, `enter`, and `append`:

```
var horizontalGrids = innerCanvas
    .selectAll(".horzGrid")
    .data(yAxisData)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "horzGrid")
    .attr("d", lineFunction(dataSet))
  .attr("d", function(d, i) {
    var p1 = {
      x: 0,
      y: yAxisScale(d)
    };
    var p2 = {
      x: marginRight - 100,
      y: yAxisScale(d)
    };
    var pts = [];
    pts.push(p1);
    pts.push(p2);
    return lineFunction(pts);
  })
    .attr("stroke", "gray")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("fill", "gray");
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/l8GdHu61Qnw7BMqXaWwy?p=preview).

Comment: Oh Mark, stackoverflow should add a button and associated message like  "Mark is currently working on a jsFiddle for this question", so that I know :)

Comment: @meetamit, ha, ha, you beat me to it again!

Comment: Yeah, but yours are usually more detailed and include an example. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
var horizontalGrids = innerCanvas
      .data(yAxisData)
    .append("path")
    ...
```

you need

```
var horizontalGrids = innerCanvas
      .data(yAxisData);

horizontalGrids.enter()
    .append("path")
    ...
```

Comment: Perfect answer.  It was staring me right in the face, too.  Thx!